# Create Forms Dynamically on Channel Entry

Tags: solspace-freeform

So basically I am creating an RSVP for a site. I would like to allow the client to just make a simple entry for an event (Name, Date, Description). I would then like to have each entry page have a version of the same RSVP form which is tailored for that event.

I was thinking of making hidden fields that would pass the name and date to the form, but if possible I would like to have Freeform track the entries separately by event. Is it possible for Freeforms to create a new 'Form' to track this data in upon the creation of an entry in a Channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a form inside a channel entries tag, and pass entry variables into the form as hidden fields, eg, if you have a Freeform field called "event_name":

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="events}
<h1>{title}</h1>
{description}

  <form>
  <input type="hidden" name="event_name" value="{title}">
  ...
  </form>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Freeform will then store the event's entry Title in it's event_name field so you can track and filter submissions.